# Is Titebond All Purpose White Glue just a diluted version of the Quick & Thick?

Tags: glue

Not technically a woodworking question, but a question about woodworking products...

I am looking for an affordable white glue to use making cardboard furniture. I'd be bonding cardboard to itself and paper. All of the videos I've seen have shown people using a pva glue that they've thinned with water and painted on with a brush, sort of a home-made decoupage glue. An 8oz bottle of All Purpose White Glue is $11 whereas the super thick formula, Quick & Thick, is only $4. Can I just mix the Quick & Thick with water and save myself a ton of money??

Comment: As this isn't a woodworking query per so I'm voting to close. However to answer your Question, you can most definitely use a thicker PVA and thin it down a little for paper/card work. In terms of the differences between the two product types in actual fact the PVA glues marketed specifically to woodworkers are fundamentally the same as basic PVAs, like Elmer's, sold for craft and general-purpose uses.

Comment: @Graphus I for one would like to keep this open. Although the specific application here is not wood, the question itself is about woodworking products and I see value in the question and your answer.

Comment: @aaron, I like to be inclusive but the Question specifically states that it's not about woodworking per se. *Plenty* of possible queries that could cover woodworking materials or tools used for something else and I'm not sure if it's a good idea to start a precedent. Another example, would a Q asking for recommendations of backsaw but the OP states it's for cutting plastic actually be good for here even though most backsaws *are* made specifically for cutting wood? I'd have to say no. Non-woodworky stuff in a woodworking context, (mostly) yes; woodworky stuff not used for woodworking, no.

Comment: @Graphus in this case though, it's about cardboard, which is a paper/wood product, so glues that are good for one are likely to be good for the other. Cutting/working plastic OTOH is really very different in terms of material properties and considerations (heat, gumming up, etc.)

Comment: @aaron, fair point that plastic is a completely different material and all that implies. And yeah most paper/card are made from wood. My main point is about the principle, but even putting that aside WRT this, how paper products work with glue is different enough from wood that there really are no direct parallels, e.g. difference in workable glue viscosities, requirement for pressure to ensure joint strength and actually what joint strength is actually required (very very much higher for wood).

Comment: @Graphus heh, i agree, that's all true. However, the original question "Is titebond all-purpose white glue just a diluted version of the quick & thick?" seems to me totally relevant to woodworking as well given that those are both specifically woodworking glues.

Comment: @aaron, but then not to read selectively ;-) it goes on to state, *"I'd be bonding cardboard to itself and paper."* So coming full circle, not about woodworking per se.